# columnGroupShow in vue of ag-grid mo found

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

my html

```
              <ag-grid-vue style="height: 100%;"
                 class="ag-theme-alpine"
                 :columnDefs="columnDefs"
                 :rowData="records"
                 :gridOptions="gridOptions"
                 :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
                 :debug="true"
                 >
             </ag-grid-vue>
```

my json headers

```
         this.columnDefs = [
                     {
            headerName:'Datos del productos',
            children:[
                {headerName:'Código Interno', columnGroupShow: 'open', field: 'internal_id',  },
                {headerName:'Unidad', columnGroupShow: 'open', field: 'unit_type_id', width: 120,suppressSizeToFit:true,  },
                {headerName:'Nombre', columnGroupShow: 'open', field: 'name',  },
                {headerName:'Ver',   columnGroupShow: 'open', filter:false , width: 80, suppressSizeToFit:true},
                {headerName:'Descripción ampliada',  columnGroupShow: 'open', field: 'description', width: 200, suppressSizeToFit:true},
                {headerName:'Código Barras', columnGroupShow: 'open', field: 'barcode'},
                {headerName:'Código SUNAT', columnGroupShow: 'open', field: 'item_code'},
                {headerName:'Código de importación', columnGroupShow: 'open', field: ''},
            ],
        },
      }
```

I would like to hide or show the columns that I have, but when setting the configuration the columngroupshow in open or closed does not work in the html

not found is group show in column, please help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that all of the children columns have `columnGroupShow:'open'`. In other words, this has **no effect**.

To fix this, have **one** column that has `columnGroupShow:'closed'` or without the property at all.